# Convert CSS border-radius % values to px dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pixel

My CSS has a class `circle` that contains `border-radius: 50%`. Unfortunately, some browsers don't support the %, and render the circle as a square. I want to dynamically convert the percentages to pixel values for browsers that don't support the percentages.

How can I accomplish this with JavaScript / jQuery?

Comment: Err, all browsers support %.  Very few fully support border-radius.  It is far, far, far more likely that that is why the browsers are rendering squares.

Comment: @rockerest: If I do `border-radius: 5px` it works and if i do `border-radius: 50%` it doesn't.

Comment: does the object have a width?  border-radius (percents) are calculated based on the width of the box.  I'm not sure how it would behave if the width is calculated by the browser and not coded in.  **edit** firefox does alright basing border-radius on automatically calculated widths, AFAI can tell.

Comment: @Rito that actually isn't the case, at least in firefox.  @Anonymous are you using firefox?  you need the -moz addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#circle').css("border-radius",$('#circle').width()/2);
```

See the example http://jsfiddle.net/cZqQ8/

Apparently you should use `-moz-border-radius` to work with mozilla

Comment: I'm using all of the following: `border-radius`, `-moz-border-radius`, `-webkit-border-radius` and `-ms-border-radius`.

Comment: I think you mean `.circle`, not `#circle`.

Comment: if the div has `id='circle'` use `#circle` if it's `class='circle'` use `.circle`

Answer (score 1):

Try this dude :

```
$('.circle').css("border-radius",$('.circle').width()/2);
```